# Asus laptop stuck on logo after bios update

Tags: bios, asus-laptop

I just updated my Asus N552VX laptop's bios from version 206 to 304. 206 was the one that came with the laptop. 304 is the latest available on their website for my laptop. I used a fat32 usb drive and the easy flash method in the bios settings to update bios. I have taken a video of the update process. After it finished updating the bios, my laptop rebooted. Ever since, I am stuck on Asus logo and F2 no longer opens bios settings.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/axbvAnti1rMARjYj9

Update: If I remove my ssd, I can access bios! However with my ssd plugged in i cannot. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As a user the only thing you can try is removing/unplugging its battery **and** CMOS battery (it's usually CR2032) - that will reset BIOS settings. In case it doesn't help, you'll have to bring the laptop to a computer/electronics service center - probably they'll be able to flash the old BIOS using a programmator but that's not certain.

Sometimes a BIOS update can take a lot of time. Never ever try to interrupt it, e.g. never press power/reset/sleep buttons or remove the power. Let if finish until you see an OS loading.

Comment: Can you check my updated question?

Comment: @dimitris93 try to reset bios settings, it's usually called "Load optimized settings" and reboot.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. The settings seems to have already been default

Comment: Try using another SSD or downgrade the BIOS (which might or might not be possible). You don't have that many options left.